# Increment list index in a while loop

Tags: python-2.7, fibonacci

I'm trying to print the first 12 numbers in the Fibonacci. My idea is to increment the two list index numbers.

```
list = [0,1] #sets the first two numbers in the fibonacci sequence to be added, as well as the list i will append the next 10 numbers

listint = list[0] #sets the list variable I want to incremented 
list2int = list[1] #set the other list variable to be incremented

while len(list) < 13:       #sets my loop to stop when it has 12 numbers in it
    x = listint + list2int       #calculates number at index 2
    list.append(x)     #appends new number to list
    listint += 1    #here is where it is supposed to be incrementing the index
    list2int +=1
print list
```

My output is:

```
[0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21]
```

I want:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89
```

Please note I am a beginner, and I'm trying to do this without using an built in functions. (I'm sure there is some sort of fibonacci sequence generator).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the first line of the while loop:

```
list = [0,1] #sets the first two numbers in the fibonacci sequence to be added, as well as the list i will append the next 10 numbers

listint = list[0] #sets the list variable I want to incremented 
list2int = list[1] #set the other list variable to be incremented

while len(list) < 12:       #sets my loop to stop when it has 12 numbers in it
    x = list[listint] + list[list2int]       #calculates number at index 2
    list.append(x)     #appends new number to list
    listint += 1    #here is where it is supposed to be incrementing the index
    list2int +=1
print list
```

Also to get the 1st 12 numbers you can set your while loop condition to < 12 because Python list indices start from 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the two last lines of the while loop. You are adding 1 each time instead of using the last two elements of the list that are the previous fibonacci numbers:

```
list = [0,1] #sets the first two numbers in the fibonacci sequence to be added, as well as the list i will append the next 10 numbers

listint = list[0] #sets the list variable I want to incremented 
list2int = list[1] #set the other list variable to be incremented

while len(list) < 13:       #sets my loop to stop when it has 12 numbers in it
    x = listint + list2int       #calculates number at index 2
    list.append(x)     #appends new number to list
    listint = list[-2]    #here is where it is supposed to be incrementing the index
    list2int = list[-1]
print list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [0,1]

while len(list) < 12:
    list.append(list[len(list)-1]+list[len(list)-2])
print list
```

Not very performant, but quick and dirty.
use < 12 because in 11th loop you'll add the 12th entry to the list.
With list[x] you access the x number of entry starting with 0 for the first entry.

edit:
output

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```